# All NextJS pages have almost the same JS bundle size

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, next.js

So, I've been working with NextJS for a while now and I never really looked at the build folder nor the info shown in the console when the build succeeds but I did notice something strange the one time I *did* look at it.

I have been using TypeScript and wrote a little babel config with TS's config to use absolute paths. So the way I am importing components is by having an absolute path **~/components** which is an alias of **./src/components**. All imports throughout the app are using components imported from **~/components** and there's other absolutes paths in there as well. So, here's what I saw when I built my app

[image]

Notice how every single page is almost of the same size? Even the **about** and **404** pages are HUGE. So my guess was that importing modules using the absolute imports is what's causing the issue and because of that, each page is linking to a JS file that has the entire app code in it . I am not exactly sure and I can't seem to find any resources online that can help me optimize these pages. Honestly, I don't even know what part of the app needs to be configured. Whether it's webpack or babel, I have no clue. So, I was hoping to get some help on this and if there's some further configuration that I have to add so each page uses only as much JavaScript as it needs.

Here's my typescript and babel configs:

TypeScript

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "~/components": ["./components"],
      "~/styles": ["./styles"],
      "~/assets": ["./assets"],
      "~/types": ["./types"],
      "~/pages": ["./pages"],
      "~/utils": ["./utils"],
      "~/context": ["./context"],
      "~/data": ["./data"],
      "~/services": ["./services"]
    },
    "allowJs": false,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Babel

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    ["styled-components", { "ssr": true }],
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "~/components": "./src/components",
          "~/styles": "./src/styles",
          "~/types": "./src/types",
          "~/pages": "./src/pages",
          "~/assets": "./src/assets",
          "~/utils": "./src/utils",
          "~/context": "./src/context",
          "~/data": "./src/data",
          "~/services": "./src/services"
        }
      }
    ],
    ["import", {
      "libraryName": "antd",
      "style": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: You seem to be looking at the wrong column. The column you are looking at is the cost of the base app + these splitted resources. i.e. 913kB + the page size

Comment: Yes, that's right but why is 913KB common among all files? The 404 page, for instance, has just two lines of code in it but that also takes 913KB of JavaScript on first load.

Comment: It's the cost of all the framework/libraries etc that are shared by your pages (things like react, router, etc etc). If only one or two of your pages actually use this common code, you may be able to refactor such that these pages do a dynamic import of the dependency rather than it sitting in the base app, but any solution would be very much dependent on your specific setup.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Comment: But the code being shared by every page is 913KB even for pages that have almost no code in them? Do absolute imports have anything to do with this cause I believe relative imports would cause some file decrease but I don't want to go with that approach

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases This explains using path aliases and absolute imports but the way they import a component is by appending the component name at the end. So it's going directly to the file. What I am doing instead is something like this import { Header, Footer, MainContent} from '~/components'

Comment: You're thinking about this wrong. Every page depends on a whole bunch of framework/libs to display. You need a router. You need react. You need react-dom. You need a whole bunch of stuff that isn't included in each page in order to show that page. Without that underlying framework, your pages make no sense... they will contain references to react, for instance, that without the underlying ***shared*** framework, can't be resolved.

Comment: Yes I got that. What didn't make a lot of sense to me was a 913Kb common bundle size. What I really wanted to know was if importing from an index file that exports multiple components out is different from using a path to the file directly and if that causes a file size increase. So if my absolute path ~/components refers to an index file (/src/components/index.ts) that is exporting out 50 components and I import only 3 from there in a page using this syntax import { Comp1, Comp2, Comp3 } from '~/components', will the rest of them also end up in the final bundle or only those 3 will?

Comment: I'm wooly on code-splitting specifics, but I have a suspicion that imports (non-dynamic `import x from y` style) that are shared by 2 or more pages might end up in the base-asset. You'd have to check though. `react-static` has tooling to analyse what ends up in your bundles. IDK so much about nextjs. If you do have imports that are shared between 2 or more pages, but are not "common", dynamic import is the way forward here, see above.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the help. I'll create a new basic Next app and try importing both using absolute and relative paths and build the app to see what happens with the bundle sizes. I'll also check out the package you mentioned. That should reveal something as well. Again, thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: This looks like the kind of tool that might help you make better informed choices about next steps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/bundle-analyzer

Comment: Ah yes! Definitely checking this out as well. Thanks!

Comment: @yourAverageDeveloper were you able to figure this out? I am in a similar situation with a huge first load JS size shared by all, and even files with 2 lines of code have sizes ~1MB

Comment: @AbhishekPatel I've added my findings in an answer to my question in the thread. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So here's what I have been able to figure out after doing some research. When you're importing stuff from a file that exports out a bunch of React components, your module bundler is not intelligent enough (yet) to figure out which components you'll be using so it includes all of them by default and therefore you have a massive bundle.

So regardless of whether you're using the components, they will all still be included in one giant bundle. Nextjs does [Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#root) by default using Webpack but since every single component is coming from the same path which is my case was **~/components**, Next (or Webpack) couldn't split it up so it included them all in one bundle which got added to every page regardless of whether the page was importing one component or a 100 from that path.

So that's the reason why I was seeing huge bundle sizes for every page. I had close to a 1000 components living inside **~/components** and I had an index file in that directory that exported out all the them. This way I could simply do

```
import { Component101, Component204 } from '~/components'
```

But the bundle size was MASSIVE. So, to solve this, I added **Tree Shaking** to my Webpack config. The term comes from Rollup originally which is another popular module bundler like Webpack. If you're using Webpack, more info on Tree Shaking can be found [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

With Tree Shaking, any piece of code that isn't being imported anywhere will be shaved off and not be included in the bundle so you will get smaller bundles. But do keep an eye out for any side-effects. Here's what my bundle size for all pages looks like after adding Tree Shaking:

[image: After Tree Shaking]

If you don't want to use Tree Shaking, another way would be to just use relative imports but I am not sure if that would be the recommended approach for large scale apps.

Comment: Congratulations great answer! Keep it up!

Comment: Thanks for answering this. Indeed this is the main problem that everyone faces in nextjs mainly

Comment: Can you provide example config to setup in next JS ?

Answer (score 0):

The comments of [this pull request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/10014) explain everything.

> This pull request updates a page's "Size" to only be its own set of dependencies.

> This PR also adds a new "First Load" column which includes shared size, and moves coloring to that column (since first load is what matters for budgets).